# Haskell: Split a list using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, split, list-comprehension, miranda

How do you split a list into halves using list comprehension?

e.g. If I have `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]`  and I only want `[1,1,2,2,3]`

my attempts so far:

```
half mylist = [r | mylist!r ; r <- [0..(#mylist div 2)] ]    ||does not work
```

Any thoughts?

[Nb: This isn't actually Haskell but similar.  ! is used for indexing list, and # gives length)

Edit::

Okay so it turns out that

```
half mylist = [r | r <- [mylist!0..mylist!(#mylist div 2)] ]
```

works,  but only in list of numbers and not strings. Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't really an appropriate thing to do with a list comprehension. List comprehensions are alternate syntax for maps and filters (and zips). Splitting a list is a fold.

As such, you should consider a different approach. E.g.

```
halve :: [a] -> [a]
halve [] = []
halve xs = take (n `div` 2) xs
    where n = length xs
```

Splitting isn't a great operation on large lists, since you take the length first (so it is always *n* + *n/2* operations on the list. It is more appropriate for array-like types that have *O(1)* length and split.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but this just wont work in Miranda. There's no splitAt function...

Comment: Can I just point out that Miranda is a dead language. Nonetheless, you can still implement `splitAt` yourself, as `splitAt n xs = (take n xs, drop n xs)` -- and we should just use `take` anyway :)

Comment: Ha trust me I'm fully aware of how dead Miranda is. Unfortunately my lecturer wrote the textbook on it, and as such we are forced to learn it. It is quite fun though.

Comment: 'take'! Wow, I completely missed that function. Yes this solves things immensely --- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution, using a boolean guard:

```
half xs = [x | (x,i) <- zip xs [1..], let m = length xs `div` 2, i <= m]
```

But as Don Stewart says, a list comprehension is not really the right tool for this job.

Comment: It's at first surprising, but this is just about as efficient as dons' suggestion or the more obvious `take n mylist where n = length mylist \`div\` 2` Dunno  what the Miranda implementation would do.